# Query the last few rows in Spreadsheet or SQL

Tags: sql, google-sheets, spreadsheet

*A1* contains the unique transposed data of Sheet1's *A*

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(QUERY(Sheet1!$A:$A;"select A";1)))
```

*A2* contains the following code:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!$A:$B;"select B where A like '%"&A1&"%'";0)
```

*Sheet1* has col *A* with label *name* and col *B* with label *height*

there are different amount of data for names, this is why i want to list only the newest data.
so:
**how can i reduce the *A2*'s query to show only the last 3 content without sorting data?** (updated question)

UPDATE:
the following strategy can be a solution, bu hope there is more clean way to do:
always add new data above the *Sheet1*'s content then adding `limit 3` to the query.

here is the sandbox: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As_Zg0RxlMgXdFR2M3RpT05MX01tSlRKR0RrTXlFb0E&usp=sharing

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward application of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses. If you know which columns you're sorting with, check here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: don't want to use ORDER BY, because the person's height not only increasing.

Comment: You must be ordering by *something* if the concept of a "last row" exists, yes? It doesn't have to be height. Maybe it's a timestamp or row number?

Comment: timestamp can be a solution, but sadly the pasted _31.07.2013 07:48_ format can't be sorted as time.

Comment: see _last3_heights_offset_ in your spreadsheet and my answer. You may use _offset_ clause. However, most efficient solution would be to write custom function in googlescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eaposztrof, chopie, kurczę

`QUERY` + `LIMIT` will do the trick only if most recent row is first.

However, if most recent row is at bottom - `QUERY` solution will do the trick if appropriately `OFFSET` used. Yet to use `OFFSET` on data without any sequence/date identifier, you need to count rows of content and assume last ones are most recent. This forces usage of `FILTER` - another query like thing.

Consider adding timestamps to original datasheet and use simply single FILTER / SORT formula. For now, this will have your data displayed as required:

`QUERY(Sheet1!$A:$B;"select B where A like '%"&A1&"%' offset "&(COUNT(FILTER(Sheet1!$B2:$B;Sheet1!$A2:$A=A1))-3);0)`

Trick is to use `offset` clause from Google Query Language (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Offset), which bypassess first X rows. We can get last 3 rows by calculating offset. Since you have no timestamp or id, assumption is the bottom row is most recent and you want to disregard starting rows:

1. counting rows matching criteria `COUNT(FILTER(Sheet1!$B2:$B;Sheet1!$A2:$A=A1))` (this FILTER inside QUERY I don't like - not efficient)
2. Substract "3" to get offset (that's why hardcoded `-3` after `COUNT`.

Most efficient solution would be to write own script with function for `=myfunction` alike usage (unfortunately, to have script with .setValues allowed this function needs to be added either to some event or upper menu bar, yet this is separate story).